# Git Bash cannot be initialized

Tags: git, bash, dll

[image]

When i use git bash it says"Failed to fork child process: Resource temporarily unavailable.DLL rebasing may be required. See 'rebaseall --help'."
How can I fix this problem?

When I use tortoiseGit to stash I got some message like this

```
> git.exe stash save -- "12"

0 [main] sh (7224) D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x1360400/0x12F0400.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
0 [main] sh 13140 fork: child -1 - forked process 7224 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\mingw32/libexec/git-core\git-stash: fork: retry: No child processes
```

Comment: what version of Git are you using? On which OS? (Windows 32 or 64 bits?)

Comment: OS  Win10 X64  Git version  v2.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead the portable version of [Git for Windows 2.9.2](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.9.2.windows.1):

- unzip [`PortableGit-2.9.2-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.9.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.9.2-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want (like `D:\git\git2.9.2`),
- remove from your PATH `D:\Program Files (x86)\Git` related paths
- add to your PATH `D:\git\git2.9.2;D:\git\git2.9.2\bin;D:\git\git2.9.2\cmd;D:\git\git2.9.2\usr\bin`

Then, from a CMD session:

- cd to a git repo
- type `bash -i --login` and check the bash works properly

Answer (score 21):

I had faced the same issue one morning. I tried to uninstall the Git just to see if it was corrupted and it pointed me to shut down few processes that go like `sh.exe` in the Task manager. After I killed them, I was able to open the Git bash successfully.

Cheers!

Comment: The OP probably meant `ssh.exe` instead of `sh.exe`, and yes -- killing these worked for me as well. Thanks for saving me the trouble of doing a full reboot.

Comment: I have `sh.exe` and not `ssh.exe` !

Comment: It was ssh.exe for me.

Comment: Want to add that for me it was `bash.exe`. Look for either `sh.exe` or `bash.exe` and kill the process.

Comment: I had the same issue and had to kill ssh-agent.exe

Comment: under windows 7 it was `bash.exe` for me

Comment: under Windows 10 killed ssh.exe and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Here is the fix.

1. Go to you Windows Defender Security Center settings
2. Click on App & Browser Control
3. At the bottom click on the "Exploit Protection Settings" link
4. Go to "Program Settings" and click on the "Add program to customize"
   -> "Choose exact file path"
5. Add "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe" and "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe"
6. Override and turn off the following: Mandatory ASLR, Randomize memory allocations (Bottom-up ASLR)
7. Click "Apply" and now everything should work fine.

Also add these other binaries from the same folder: expr.exe, uname.exe, grep.exe, rm.exe

Good luck,
Gabriel

Comment: but why does aslr has anything to do with git?

Answer (score 0):

In my case since git bash was working before restarting my machine fix the issue.

Try by restarting your machine first, Hopefully it will fix it.